# Adding different geom_segment to every facet

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the code below, and it works fine. The problem is, I would like to add "k" and plot a straight line similar to "z", but "k" is a vector of different numbers. Each element in "k" should be plotted as a line on the 3 facets created. If k was a singular value, I would just repeat the geom_segment() command with different y limits. Is there an easy way to do this? The final output should look like attached, assuming I could draw straight lines.

```
x <- iris[-1:-3]
bw <- 1
nbin <- 100
y <- head(iris, 50)[2]
z <- 1
k <- c(2, 3, 4)
    
ggplot(x, aes(x = Petal.Width)) +
  geom_density(aes(y = bw *..count.., fill = Species), size = 1, alpha = 0.4) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = 5, y = 250, xend = z, yend = 250, color = "red")) +
  facet_wrap(~Species)+
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::math_format(10^.x), limits = c(0, 5), expand = c(0,0)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0), limits = c(0, NA)) +
  annotation_logticks(sides = "b", short=unit(-1,"mm"), mid=unit(-2,"mm"), long=unit(-3,"mm")) +
  coord_cartesian(clip='off') + theme(panel.background = element_blank(), 
                                      panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA))
```

[image]

Comment: It could be, but it doesn't really matter where as long as the line is there. I could always adjust the y values in geom_segment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this. Assuming that your plot is saved as p1.

```
k_data = data.frame(k, Species = levels(x$Species))
p1 + geom_segment(data = k_data, aes(x =5, y = 200, xend = k, yend = 200), 
                  color = "blue", inherit.aes = F)
```

[image]

The idea is to create a dataframe with the columns k and Species and use this data exclusivley in a geom by setting inherit.aes = F

Comment: I also tried without the inherit.aes = F, and output is the same. Why do you think it is necessary?

Comment: You are right. In this case it is fine. If there are further columns in the helper data, e.g. with same names, then your legend or even the plot could be destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

In this solution, the value of `k` is made part of the data set being plotted through a pipe. It is a temporary modification of the data set, since it is not assigned back to it nor to any other data set.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

x <- iris[-1:-3]
str(x)
bw <- 1
nbin <- 100
y <- head(iris, 50)[2]
z <- 1
k <- c(2, 3, 4)

x %>%
  mutate(k = rep(k, each = 50)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Petal.Width)) +
  geom_density(aes(y = bw *..count.., fill = Species), size = 1, alpha = 0.4) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = 5, y = 250, xend = z, yend = 250), color = "red") +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 5, y = 200, xend = k, yend = 200), color = "blue") +
  facet_wrap(~Species)+
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::math_format(10^.x), limits = c(0, 5), expand = c(0,0)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0), limits = c(0, NA)) +
  annotation_logticks(sides = "b", short=unit(-1,"mm"), mid=unit(-2,"mm"), long=unit(-3,"mm")) +
  coord_cartesian(clip='off') + 
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(), 
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA))
```

[image]

Comment: I chose Roman's answer just because in my actual dataset, the size of the dataset can vary between the Species, so adding "each = 50" in mutate wouldn't work out without some tweaks.

Comment: @user13589693 You are right, Roman's answer is much better.

Comment: I'm not sure if its better. It depends on the data. You can use `mutate(k = rep(k, each = n()/nlevels(Species)))` to generalize the function.